# How does group multiplication interact with this intersection of subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

I'm working through the book *Algebra (Revised Third Edition)* by Serge Lang. I'm having trouble simplifying terms in one of the exercises (Ch. 1 Ex. 8b). The question goes as follows:

> Let $G$ be a group and let $H,~H'$ be subgroups. By a **double coset**
> of $H,~H'$ one means a subset of $G$ of the form $HxH'$. Let $\{c\}$
> be a family of representatives for the double cosets. For each $a\in G$
> denote by $[a]H'$ the conjugate $aH'a^{-1}$ of $H'$. For each $c$
> we have a decomposition into ordinary cosets
> $$H=\bigcup_{x_c} x_c(H\cap [c]H'),$$
> where $\{x_c\}$ is a family of elements of $H$, depending on
> $c$. Show that the elements $\{x_cc\}$ form a family of left coset
> representatives for $H'$ in $G$; that is,
> $$G = \bigcup_{c}\bigcup_{x_c}x_ccH',$$
> and the union is disjoint.

From question 8a, I already know that
$$\begin{align*}
G&=\bigsqcup_{c}HcH'\\
 &=\bigsqcup_{c}\big(\bigcup_{x_c}x_c(H\cap(cH'c^{-1}))\big)cH'\\
 &=\bigsqcup_{c}\bigcup_{x_c}x_c(H\cap(cH'c^{-1}))cH'
\end{align*}$$
I know that $Hc=H$, but I'm stuck: I'm not sure how $x_c$ and $cH'$ interact/distribute with the intersection $H\cap(cHc^{-1})$ and for what reason. Can I get a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My reasoning would be this.

Let $g\in G$. Then we have $g=hch'$, where $h\in H$ and $h'\in H'$.
Further, we have $h=x_cb$, where $b\in H\cap(cH'c^{-1})$.
It follows that $g=x_cbch'=x_cc(c^{-1}bc)h'=x_cch''h'\in x_ccH'$, where $h''=c^{-1}bc\in H'$.

Now let us prove that cosets $x_ccH'$ are pairwise distinct.
Let $x_ccH'=y_{c'}c'H'$. Then we have $HcH'=Hc'H'$.
It follows that $c=c'$.
Since $x_ccH'=y_{c}cH'$ we have $y_{c}c=x_cch'$, where $h'\in H'$.
It follows that $x_c^{-1}y_c\in H\cap(cH'c^{-1})$ $\Rightarrow$ $y_c=x_c$.

Comment: @koenk, thank you for correcting my typos